# Can Razor be used with visual studio 2008?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-3

Scott Gu didn't talk about this in his blog post. Will there be intellisense support for razor on vs 2008? MS is giving everyone a hard time by releasing major upgrades so frequently :D

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No, not just Razor but MVC 3 will not be supported in VS 2008. The reason is that MVC 3 is being compiled on .NET 4.0 which is also not supported in VS 2008.

Comment: Does Razor need MVC 3? I was under the impression that it could run on MVC 2 too. Me not right?

Comment: MVC 3 and Razor only run on .NET 4

Comment: Razor does not need MVC 3 but MVC 3 needs Razor.

Comment: @Praveen, you are confusing it with ASPX and Razor, you can combind both of them. But in ASP.NET MVC 3.

Comment: guess where the link to download the Razor?
I have installed on my pc MVC2 + Visual Studio 2008 SP1

Comment: Is there some plugin / addin that can enable mvc 3 in vs 2008 ?

Comment: No, but you can download VS2010 express for free.