# Can I use MVC3 in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to know if MVC3 architecture can be used in Visual Studio 2008.
I am using SQL Server 2008.

Please provide suggestions. You can give me any link to a tutorial.

Please tell me about only Visual Studio 2008, not about 2010.

Comment: Answer: [Can Razor be used with visual studio 2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429336/can-razor-be-used-with-visual-studio-2008)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

MVC3 was build for .net 4.0 Framework.
There is no support for .net 4.0 Framework in VS 2008.

So answer to your question is No you cannot use  MVC3 in Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can't.
MVC3 require .net framework 4.