# How to create an ASP.net MVC Project with aspx engine as default

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a new project for ASP.net MVC application (2.0) in MS Visual Studio 2008.

It is creating application with Razor as default view engine. It is not asking for choosing view engine, it is just asking whether the test project is required or not

Please help me on this

Comment: follow project creation wizard carefully. you will find it.

Comment: Remember that this is VS2008 (for some reason). It may not be an option.

Comment: Razor requires .NET 4.0. Visual Studio 2008 doesn't support .NET 4.0. So telling that Razor is the default view engine in VS 2008 seems pretty strange to me and hardly makes any sense.

Comment: Agree with @DarinDimitrov

Comment: You might want to check http://stackoverflow.com/a/3429363/309395  @Avinash

Comment: Sorry , i was using MS Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

MVC 2.0 doesn't have razor engine. Razor engine only exist only in mvc3 on wards

however on switching view engines this topic might help you

http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/switching-aspx-razor-view