# .cshtml files are not getting visible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to MVC and in the learning phase. I Just installed the VS2010 in my system and trying to learn, by making a small application in the MVC but when I saw the tutorial there were some files in view folder having extension of .cshtml but when I created the project there was no file like this there were only aspx files, so where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Consider installing VS 2013... I don't remember if Razor views had good support in 2010...

Comment: you need to select razor while creating your project.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2010 does support Razor Views.
When creating a new MVC Project in VS just select Razor instead of ASPX in the View Engine Drop Down List.

Please see this link for and example Screen Shot: http://postimg.org/image/g15x54sbx/

Comment: +1 VS 2010 supports Razor View. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429336/can-razor-be-used-with-visual-studio-2008

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of view engine available in Visual Studio 10. You need to select Rajor view engine while creating your project.

You can see following link for your reference.
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose the view engine as **"Razor"**. Then it will create the view as .cshtml

[image: Choose Razor]